# Ajax request catches error on localhost, but not on server

Tags: javascript, ajax, error-handling, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to write a javascript function that tries reading text files from the server until it finds one that doesn't exist.
On the server there are text files numbered 1 to n (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt etc.), so it should read all the files (sequentially or asynchronously) until it tries to read "4.txt" and it throws an error.

The following code works on my local machine (with no server running), but fails on a remote server saying the "No such file" error is uncaught.

I am trying to understand why the error is handled differently in the two cases, if there is anything I can do to make it work for a remote server as well, and if there is any other approach I can take for this?

The minimal code I have is:

```
var files=[];

function readTextFile(file)
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", file, false);
    request.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(request.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(request.status === 200)
            {
                var allText = request.responseText;
                files.push(allText);
            } else {
                throw "No such file";
            }
        }
    }
    request.send();
}

function readFiles(){
    try {
        var i =1;
        while (true) {
            readTextFile(i+".txt");
            i+=1;
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("finished reading files")
    }
    console.log(files)
}

readFiles();
```

Comment: 'while' itself is a synchronous operation and does not wait for async operations. Different results are probably due to speed/latency difference. To eliminate, you need to use an async loop mechanism such as https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Good guess, but he is already making non-async HTTP requests... OP, could it be a permissions issue on the remote server?

Comment: Yes, I am making non-async requests in the while loop. I do not think it's a permission issue. The files load the same, except it never catches the exception and never quits the loop.

Comment: What messages do you see in the devtools console?

Comment: `Uncaught No such file`
`rawFile.onreadystatechange @ test.js:16`
`readTextFile @ test.js:20`
`readFiles @ test.js:27`
`(anonymous) @ test.js:37`